# Not getting action when pressing UIButton inside a custom static cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Using iOS5. I dragged a UIButton object to inside a custom static cell. Since I am not using dynamic properties I am not using the data source template. The thing is that I am unable to trigger any event when pressing that UIButton inside the cell. I am running the folioing code in my table view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [medicareTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
    UIButton *stepNumberOfChildren = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:222];

    [stepNumberOfChildren addTarget:self action:@selector(dontTouchMe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

}
- (void)dontTouchMe:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Touched Button %i",((UIButton *)sender).tag);
}
```

Run the app, press the UIButton and it does not log anything... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to change 1 to 0 in this line `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];`

Comment: In viewDidLoad you might not get tableviewcell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 2):

Connect your outlet to dontTouchMe function (TouchUpInside)

Comment: Thanks! My outlet was not hooked up. For some reason the NSLog is not kicked off but the button event is really pushed as I could invoke other calls.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to add the target only to the cell at row=1 and section=1

So code as follows,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(indexpath.row==1&&indexpath.section==1)
   {
   //add the button target
   }
}
```